# Convert non english string to normal String in Java

Tags: java

I am required to validate certain text against some baselines.

For ex:

```
String a="La PanthÃ¨re"; 
String b="La Panth&#232;re";
```

I know that string `b` contains HTML literals so I am using Apache `StringEscapeUtils` which gives me

```
String b="La Panth&#232;re";
b=StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(b);
```

Output:- La Panthère

However I do not know whats stored in string a. Somewhere from SO I got to know that this might be ascent literals and hence tried below code

```
a=Normalizer.normalize(a, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
```

Note: I tried all forms of Normalizer but nothing worked.

Can some one please help me in how to make String a in same fashion as that of `b`?

Comment: A string that looks like "La PanthÃ¨re" is most likely the result of using an incorrect character encoding.

Comment: `a = a.replace("Ã¨", "è");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Jesper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135589/jesper) mentions, the `Ã¨` pattern typically indicates a mis-encoding.

At that point, you're already out of luck.

Remedial actions such as replacing the `Ã¨` are not advisable, nor safe.

Escaping or normalizing the `String` is out of scope, as your problem is at the source and has nothing to do with HTML conversion or accent normalization.

However, there are simple idioms to convert the `String` to a different encoding.

The example below:

- simulates a Windows-1252 `String` (in a UTF-8 environment).
- then, it prints it as is (corrupted, since it's a Windows-1252 `String` in a UTF-8 print stream).
- finally, it prints it re-converted to UTF-8.

  ```
  String a = new String(
  "La Panthère".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")),
   Charset.forName("Cp1252")
  );
  System.out.println(a);
  System.out.println(
      new String(
          a.getBytes(Charset.forName("Cp1252")), 
          Charset.forName("UTF-8")
      )
  );
  ```

**Output**

```
La PanthÃ¨re
La Panthère
```

**Notes**

The conversion idiom described above implies you know how the original `String` is encoded beforehand.

Typical encoding issues take place when the following encoding are used to interpret text in one another:

- ISO Latin 1
- Windows-1252
- UTF-8

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)'s a list of Java-supported encodings along with their canonical names.

In a web context, you'd typically invoke Javascript's [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) function to encode your values in the front-end, before sending them to the back-end.